# Apart from size, what properties make for a good exercise ball?

Tags: exercise-equipment, exercise-ball

I wish to use an exercise ball as a chair. I have done this previously with several different brands of exercise ball, and it has worked for me in the past. I noticed that some balls were far comfier than others, but apart from the obvious effect of using an appropriately sized ball, I don't understand what causes one ball to be comfier than another.

What properties of an exercise ball make it more suitable for purpose as a chair? Where possible, how I can ensure a ball bought unseen (i.e. online) meets that specification?

Comment: In addition to getting the [correct size](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2062/how-do-i-determine-what-size-exercise-ball-i-should-use-as-a-desk-chair/8118#8118), consider an [anti burst](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00066DBC2/ref=as_li_tf_til?tag=howtogetbackinshape-20&camp=14573&creative=327641&linkCode=as1&creativeASIN=B00066DBC2&adid=00946VH707N1Q29NR4N0&&ref-refURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.howtogetbackinshape.com%2FUsing-An-Exercise-Ball-as-a-Desk-Chair.html) or gradual deflation feature. I don't know about it's comfort but it is a safety feature and especially helpful if you have cats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to pay attention to the texture of the ball. Some exercise balls have latitudinal ridges that help the ball grip onto surfaces. These may make a ball more comfortable to sit on since the ridges can prevent the ball from sliding around too much on wood or tile floors. This however might also make the ball less comfortable if you can actually feel the ridges when you're sitting. Usually by looking at photos you can tell if the surface of the ball is textured or not.